# PHP MySQL Getting Data Out of Multiple Tables

Tags: php, mysql

I asked a similar question yesterday which may have been poorly worded, either way I didn't understand and this is something I really need to crack :) I've never done it before and would be very useful for so many of my projects.

This is for a directory website. I have three tables: **entry**, **location**, and **entry-locations**. **entry** contains information about a building such as name, address, image, etc. **location** is simply a list of possible locations each building could be. The location table is pretty much irrelevant for this example, it just contains information about the location which I could display on other areas of the site.

**entry-locations** is a table which links the entries to the locations. It only has two fields, *entry-id* and *location*... If you're wondering why I need a seperate table for this is because the same building *could* have multiple locations (don't ask).

Basically, what I need to do is display listings from each location it's own page. For example, I need to list every building in France, so the query needs to go through the **entry-locations** table returning every record with the location 'France', then it needs to pull all the data from the **entry** table corresponding to the *entry-id*'s returned.

I'm sure there is a way to do this with one query and would be extremely greatful if I could be shown how, I could replicate this in so many projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you have this data:

**Entry**:

```
|id|name|
| 1|Foo |
| 2|Bar |
```

**Entry-Location**:

```
|entry-id|location|
|1       |France  |
|2       |Greece  |
|2       |France  |
```

This is how I understand the tables from your description. A more common approach is to have

```
Entry(id,name)
Location(id,name)
Entry_Location(entry_id, location_id)
```

This is also the source of some of the confusions in the other posts, I think.

Now, ask MySql to fetch data from both tables, where the id's match up.

```
SELECT entry.* 
FROM `entry`, `entry-location` as el
WHERE entry.id = el.`entry-id`
AND el.location = 'France';
```

MySql now treats your data like one table, looking like this:

```
|entry.id|entry.name|el.location|
|       1|       Foo|     France|
|       1|       Foo|     Greece|
|       2|       Bar|     France|
```

And from that table it selects the entries where `el.location = 'France'`, and returns the specified fields.

This query fetches all the fields from the `entry` table that matches the requirements you set. 
First it makes MySql think of the two tables as one table, by `SELECT`-ing from both of them.

Have a look at MySql's [SELECT reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

Answer (score 5):

How about this one?

```
-- // Selects all the columns from both entry-locations and entry
SELECT * 
FROM entry-locations
JOIN entry e ON e.id = el.entry-id
WHERE el.location = 'France';

-- // To just get the entry data for matching records: (Remove DISTINCT if you
-- // don't mind, or want, each entry with multiple locations in the result set
-- // multiple times)
SELECT DISTINCT e.* 
FROM entry-locations el
JOIN entry e ON e.id = el.entry-id
WHERE el.location = 'France'
```

***Edit:*** Ok, so I tried removing the location table, and instead used entry-location.location as the name of the location.. Is this correct?

Comment: Like I said the location table is completely irrelevant, it doens't need to be in the query at all. All I need is (in words): "select * from entry-locations where location = 'France'", but then I need to get the entry id's from the resulting records and display data from the entry table for each one...

Comment: How can you say that it is irrelevant when you want to constrain your results based on the location's name?

Comment: And no, you get the aggregated data from all tables you join with, ie. all columns. If you just want the data in the entry-table, see my edit above

Comment: Pretend there is only two tables, 'entry-locations' and 'entry'. 'entry-locations' contains entry-id and location, entry-id corresponds to an ID in the entry table, location is just a word. Do you understand now?

Comment: I'm not sure.. but I gave it a shot. If this is not correct, could you provide SHOW CREATE TABLE for each of the involved tables?

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `entry` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `address` text NOT NULL,
  `postcode` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `link` (
  `eid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

The entry-locations table is now called link for ease. Thanks for all your help so far!

Comment: Your last query brings up no errors so it might be working, but how using PHP can I pull and display the data? I'm using this kind of set up at the moment:

while($r=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ 

  
   $name=$r["name"];
   
   echo "$name";
}

Comment: The column name will be 'entry.name' or similar. Do a var_dump($r);

Comment: I've got to this:

while($r=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ 

   $name=var_dump($r["entry.name"]);

   echo "$name";
   echo "lol";
}

I put the echo lol in for a test, the lol is not displaying, I guess that means the query is not returning any data?

Answer (score 0):

select * from entry where id in (select entry-id from entry-locations)

Comment: Could you offer an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

If I got your idea, you need:
select e.* frmm entry join entry-locations as as l ON l.entry-id=e.id WHERE l.location='France'